# li3 cosole cli does nothing or errors out

Tags: lithium

What I'm trying to do is to create a model called Entities.
I tried to use the console to create my model "Entities" and got this error:

```
C:\>li3 create model Entities
model could not be created
```

I'm expecting an Entities.php file to be created in my models folder.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you working inside of you application directory?

Comment: I figured out the answer last night, but stack overflow wouldn't let me post it cuz I'm a newbie. Thanks though, if I saw that question when I first started banging my head against my keyboard, I would have saved myself a big bruise on my forehead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because I called li3 by putting a PATH environmental variable to the console folder where li3 lives. I think li3 freaks out cuz it can't find the models folder.

Anyway, I added the console folder to my favorites list and shift right-click on it to make cmd go to the console folder directly so I don't have to type the long path name out. Incidentally, I also found out that by typing

```
li3 create "insert model name here"
```

the CLI will create the model, controller, and tests automagically. Too bad it doesn't do the view too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the Lithium command doesn't create the views for you is mostly because everyone needs their views differently. With the Form helper at hand, it should not be a problem to get up and running quickly - and the Lithium error messages tell you where to start!